# How to retrieve content from my wordpress blog to phonegap app

Tags: wordpress, phonegap-build

Please i was wondering if there is a custom function to create a json api in wordpress instead of using a plugin. If there is can you please explain how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a REST api for wordpress that lets you do it.

Google: [wordpress rest api](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+rest+api)

Like this: [WordPress REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)